# Is there a benefit to adding JS and CSS in preprocess_html instead of theme.info?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

Most of my sites js and css is being added in theme_preprocess_html instead of using theme.info.

It doesn't seem like there is anything being applied there to prevent them from not loading in certain areas. I'm wondering if this in anyway affects caching performance or rendering performance.

Comment: It depends on how you insert the js. If you call `drupal_add_js` and `drupal_add_css` from your preprocessors, then it might not get cached properly. However if you use `#attached` then it should get cached with the array. The theme .info file is probably the most reliable if you don't need any conditions.

Comment: some have type and scope placed: `drupal_add_js('file.js', array(type,scope))`. I'm going to move them to .info file as i haven't used #attached before.